# How can I display image from get request on screen in flutter?

Tags: mongodb, image, flutter, flutter-layout, dio

I am new to flutter. I am facing issues in displaying image on the screen that I am getting from MongoDB. The image I am getting is in the format "somenameofimage.jpg" or "somenameofimage.png".
I have searched for it, but every I see NetworkImage used for loading images from internet I guess or from assets.
I am getting the result of get request in a variable that has other details like name contact etc as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use this to get image from server

```
               Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: profileData.imageAddress != null
                                      ? NetworkImage(
                                              profileData.imageAddress)
```

NetworkImage works fine for me... look at the URL for the picture put it in your browser to see if it is correct or not

this works too

```
Image.network(profileData.imageAddress,)
```

Comment: Link wont work because it will need bearer token to access profile data.

Comment: are you sure?i have not heard of something like this...you usually need bearer token to get that response not to load a picture...any way this code works fine my api needs token too

Comment: look at the URL for the picture put it in your browser to see if it is correct or not. I am getting image like fWkyUAeEVOiBajuTXxgZ1PGHoyKr7Gl--logo.jpg. How can I paste it in the browser or am I missing something?

Comment: it depends.i mostly get the full URL from backend...but it seems you havent...this URL is wrong for sure it...you may consider adding first part of url on your own ....
for Example
NetworkImage( "www.google.com/image/" + profileData.imageAddress)
if i were you i would have asked backend dev if he/she made a mistake or not